# Elasticsearch Lucene query to search for text and numbers

Tags: lucene, kibana, elk

I am using Kibana version v7.13.2.
I am trying to search for messages carrying the phrase `"amount":"3000","taxRate"`
where the amount value ranges from 3000 to 3999.
I am using the following Lucene Query:
`message:amount /3[0-9]{3}/ taxRate`

The query works and fetches the following:
`"amount":"3100","taxRate"`
`"amount":"200","taxRate"`
`"amount":"3983","taxRate"`
`"amount":"3100"`
`"taxRate"`
`"amount"`
`"3100","taxRate"`
`"amount":"3100","trxFee":"90","taxRate"`

Means the query is working with OR condition. It fetches the messages if there is word `amount` OR the number ranging from `[3000-3999]` OR the word "taxRate".

I want to modify the query to search for messages where ALL THREE PATTERNS exist together IN THAT SPECIFIC ORDER, i.e. first `amount` second `amount value` and finally the word `taxRate`

So with the correct query, the following resultSet would appear only:
`"amount":"3100","taxRate"`
`"amount":"3983","taxRate"`

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you try this filter?

`message:"amount" /3[0-9]{2}[0-9]/ "taxRate"`

Comment: @MusabDogan Its searching the messages where there are both ```amount``` and ```taxRate``` ignoring the regex in between.